# How to prevent that user can't close the Loginform which be initialized in the constructor of main form in C#

Tags: c#

here there are two forms, mainform and loginform.
First, loginform comes up because it is initialized in the constructor of the mainform.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        LoginForm frmLogin = new LoginForm();
        frmLogin.ShowDialog();
        //
    }
}
```

So I would like to prevent the user cannot closed the Loginform by [X]in the title bar because after the Main form will be appeared. with thanks

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, your design is wrong. Either your form can (and should) work without logging in, in which case the login should by bypassable, or it doesn't, and in that case, it shouldn't appear at all (or it should close on its own immediately at least). In any case, showing a dialog inside of a constructor is most likely a very bad idea :)

Comment: I think you could set `LoginForm` as first form

Comment: LoginForm is just for control who can access to program then if password is right, the program will be opened and ......

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ControlBox` property of your login form to `false`. This way there is no Minimize, Maximize or Close button in the upper right corner:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and you are right. But I'm looking for some codes that there is relevant with DialoResult

Comment: I used it in my program but I can't remember it it was like ((            
if(frmlogin.DialogResult==DialogRuslt.cancel) 
Application.ExitThread(); ))

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY problem.  You are asking for Y, the X is that you do not use ShowDialog() properly.  Never trap the user, he wants to close the dialog because he doesn't know the password.  Entirely normal of course.  Fix:

```
    using (LoginForm frmLogin = new LoginForm()) {
        if (frmLogin.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Also note the considerable W problem, prompting the user for a logon in Winforms is **never** correct.  You already know who the user is, he logged in to Windows before he started your program.  A highly secure login procedure.  Much more so than the one you added, giving an attacker many more ways to discover a username+password that he can exploit.  Logins like this are only appropriate in web applications.

Comment: `Logins like this are only appropriate in web applications.` What about e-mail clients or clients like Steam?

Comment: They are web applications.  They contact a server on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't handling the DialogResult.Cancel correctly because there is no difference between the user closing with a Close button that you've assigned as the Cancel button, and clicking the close X in the corner. You still have to do something better than "Abort, Retry, Fail" loop.

For what its worth, you can set FormBorderStyle to None and/or set ControlBox to false. Both will hide the cancel box, but the former will also keep the user from moving or resizing the dialog.

```
  private void InitializeComponent()
  {
     this.SuspendLayout();
     // 
     // Form1
     // 
     ...
     this.ControlBox = false;
     this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
     ...
     this.ResumeLayout(false);
  }
```

Nonetheless, I tend to agree with Hans Passant. Trapping the user is bad/annoying/unprofessional. Dialogs I cant close make me want to nuke the program from my PC.

Comment: You are right, but I'm looking for it's code THANKS.

Comment: Its code? Set the properties that I listed, then refer to InitializeComponent() for the code.